# ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[13])

Tags: azure, kubernetes, devops

I have a manifest of a Kubernetes `Deployment`. When I try to deploy it from Azure Devops, I get the following error:

```
error: error validating "/home/vsts/work/r1/a/_MozCom-Ace-QTR/beta/ace-ui-deploy.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[13]): missing required field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvVar; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: abc-ui
  namespace: abcqat-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: abc-ui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: abc-ui
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: abc-ui
          image: abc.azurecr.io/mozcom-abc-ui-mig:65272
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3883
              name: abc-ui
          readinessProbe:
               httpGet:
                   path: /health-probe
                   port: 3883
               initialDelaySeconds: 15
               periodSeconds: 10
               timeoutSeconds: 5
          livenessProbe:
              httpGet:
                  path: /health-probe
                  port: 3883
              initialDelaySeconds: 15
              periodSeconds: 10
              timeoutSeconds: 5
          env:
            - name: ENVIRONMENT
              value: PROD
            - name: PORT
              value: "3883"
            - name: DISABLE_CONSTRUCT_API_URL
              value: "true"
            - name: APP_API_HOST
              value: https://afgabcqtr-webapi-beta.mozcomtest.com
            - name: APP_API_PROTOCOL
              value: "https:"
            - name: SITE_NAME_SEPARATOR
              value: "-"
            - name: AUTH_SERVER_HOST
              value: https://afgabcqtr-cas-beta.mozcomtest.com
            - name: GOOGLE_MAP_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mozcom-env-secret
                  key: googleMapKey
            - name: BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED
              value: "true"
            - name: BASIC_AUTH_USER
              value: mozcomabc
            - name: BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD
              value: afgabclive
            - name: AKS_UNIQUE_KEY_DEPLOY_DATE
              value: REPLabc_WITH_DATE_STAMP
            - name: SENTRY_DNS 
              value: "https://02e9ff2a5d6b4cd4a253f32de9237ca5@o537716.ingest.sentry.io/5658030"
            - name: APPLE_PAY_MERCHANT_ID
              value: merchant.com.alfuttaim.abcuae
            - name: LOG_ROCKET_ID
              value: pjpo3x/abc
            - name: APP_API_INTERNAL_HOST
              value: 'http://web-api:8071'
            - name: AUTH_SERVER_INTERNAL_HOST
              value: 'http://cas-server:6443'
            - name: ALGOLIA_BRAND
              value: mozanta_abc
            - name: BRAND
              value: abc
            - name: APPLICATION_ID
              value: 6DAMKJX8YE
            - name: SEARCH_API_KEY
              value: 85e7bf88034b7bc60b7f0085683a19af
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you're missing `name` attribute/field in 14th environment variable (`spec.containers[0].env[13]`) of the container. However, in the manifest shared above there are no environment variables written.

Can you share the complete manifest file?

Comment: > shared the complete yaml above

Comment: Please paste the formatted yaml snippet in your question. It's difficult to understand without formatting.

Comment: I think your environment variables have indentation issues starting from 14th one. Adjust there indentations and see if the issue resolves.

Comment: they are in same line,, this is screenshot..thats why the alignment looks different

Comment: updated the yaml again

Comment: yaml updated in the question

Comment: I've applied your manifest on my on-prem k8s cluster and it works file. The `--dry-run=client` & `--dry-run=server` flags also indicate that there's no issue (`deployment.apps/abc-ui created (dry run)` and `deployment.apps/abc-ui created (server dry run) respectively)`. What does your `--dry-run` output say?